# Unrecognized selector when try to call indexPathForCell

Tags: ios, objective-c

I opened *old* Application iOS development target 4.3 in Xcode 6.1 and it crashes when I try to show Sub preferences

```
 *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', 
reason: '-[IASKPSTitleValueSpecifierViewCell indexPathForCell:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xc8cde0'
```

Relevant code:

```
UIView *view = [self superview]; 
    // Find TableViewCell
    if(view != nil && ![view isKindOfClass:[UITableView class]]) 
      view = [view superview]; // im enter here

    UIView *cellView = [self superview]; 
    // Find TableViewCell
    if(cellView != nil && ![cellView isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]]) 
       cellView = [cellView superview]; // im enter here too


  if(view != nil && cellView != nil) {
    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell*)cellView;
    UITableView *tableView = (UITableView*)view;

    if([tableView style] == UITableViewStyleGrouped) {
        NSIndexPath *path = [tableView indexPathForCell:cell]; // <-- here crash happens

 // ....
```

And this is interface:

```
@interface IASKPSTitleValueSpecifierViewCell : UITableViewCell

@end
```

**EDIT:**

Somehow `cellView` and `view` point to the same place

```
//cellView      IASKPSTitleValueSpecifierViewCell * 0xc7f680    0x00c7f680
//view          IASKPSTitleValueSpecifierViewCell * 0xc7f680    0x00c7f680
```

So what is changed since Xcode4 that old code doesn't work?

Please help,

Comment: Calling `indexPathForCell` on what looks like a `UITableViewCell` subclass can't be right can it.  So it looks like `tableView` isn't what you expect it to be.

Comment: @trojanfoe I added additional info

Comment: Just set properties `tableView` and `cell` in you class. Don't use this pornography with `if(view != nil && ![view isKindOfClass:[UITableView class]]) view = [view superview];`. This condition didn't work and your's view is pointing at cell.

Comment: From an MVC design perspective this is all wrong. A view should have no idea what's outside of it and shouldn't communicate with its superview. You should use the delegate pattern to have your cell communicate with a view controller, and your view controller can decide what to do with the table view.

Comment: I know well that is not good design (like in Java we try to avoid `instanceof`) but right now I try to solve specific issue. Thanks,

Comment: @Cy-4AH I have several levels of Preferences. It happens on inner level. The same code is called when I redirect to top level of preferences.

Comment: Do you have a showPreference button in your tableViewCell and are you trying to find out which row the user tapped the showPreference button on ?

Comment: @Zhang I have root Sharepreferences list of items with '>' icon, Each item opens sub-view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this to find tableView:

```
UITableView *tableView;
for (UIView *view = self; view != nil; view = view.superview){
    if ([view isKindOfClass:[UITableView class]])
        tableView = (UITableView*)view;
}
```

Comment: Idk who downvoted you but this solution works for me. Its not good way to do so (from view of developper) but it makes sense. Hope I'll get description why old code doesn't work

Comment: Yes, it is not best design flow, but, in this case is that, what author was need, I think yours code was not work, because you had the deeper view hierarchy.

Comment: If no one will give better solution Ill accept this one. Thanks,

Comment: Add a break; after tableView = inside your conditional there, no need to keep cycling up the tree to top once tableview is found.. Also the 'condition' (middle) argument in loop might benefit from more conditions maybe (view != nil && view.superview != nil && ![view isKindOfClass:[UIWindow class]]) ...